# Concatenate varying number of columns by partial match (R)

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation, multiple-columns

first question on SO, though I've been lurking for awhile! I tried to do my due diligence and am getting closer to the answer.

I have a 300-column data frame that I want to merge down into about 10 columns, based on matching the pattern of the variable name. The raw data output gives me a column with the primary variable name (in the example, "before" and "after") and a number. In my "real" data, there are about 30 copies of each variable.

I want to combine every column that has "before" in its name, or "after," etc.
I successfully created the variable "new" using data.table's syntax for this type of "calculated" column.

```
myTable2[, new := paste(before1, before2, sep = "")]

> myTable2
 herenow     before1 before2 before3  after1 after2 after3         new
1: 0.3399679      if     and   where     not   here  blank       ifand
2: 0.8181909     for      in      by through  blank  blank       forin
3: 0.2237681     and   where            mine  yours   ours    andwhere
4: 0.6161998     and   where              ha    hey    hon    andwhere
5: 0.7606252   fifth  eighth     and   where    not   beet fiftheighth
6: 0.5525105     and   where     not    fill           are    andwhere
```

But as you see, that is explicitly saying the columns I want to combine. I want to flexibly combine, such that if I have 31 copies of one variable and 86 of another I don't a) have to know that or b) have to type that. I just want to match based on the base variable name (e.g. "before") and combine the columns.

I tried to go to the next level using grep...

```
> newvar2 <- paste(grep("before", colnames(myTable2), value = TRUE), collapse = "")
> newvar2
[1] "before1before2before3"
```

and that confirmed to me that I can combine a variable number of values with grep pattern matching.

Next step: How do I combine these two steps such that the

```
new := paste(etc....)
```

takes the grep step as its argument and combines all those *columns* whose names match the pattern?
This is what I want:

```
 herenow        before_Final    after_Final
1: 0.339967856  ifandwhere      nothereblank
2: 0.818190875  forinby         throughblankblank
3: 0.223768051  andwhere        mineyoursours
4: 0.616199835  andwhere        haheyhon
5: 0.760625218  fiftheighthand  wherenotbeet
6: 0.552510532  andwherenot     fillare
```

I am working on learning more about vectorization, but if I could even make a list of the variable types I want to combine (e.g. before, after, between) and then run through those, possibly in a loop, that would be great! So something like

```
finalVarNames <- c("Before_final", "After_final", "Between_final")
whatToMatch <- c("before", "after", "between")
```

(For loop here...)

```
myTable2[, finalVarNames[i] := paste(grep(whatToMatch[i], myTable2, value = TRUE), collapse = "")]
```

I know that syntax isn't right, likely in the second "myTable2" reference before the value argument. This code does create the new variable successfully, but it is blank. How do I get the concatenated group of grep-matching variables into it?

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: As a starting point see `do.call(paste, c(sep = "", myTable2[startsWith(names(myTable2), whatToMatch[i])]))`

Comment: `c()` isn't taking a `sep=` argument. The docs say the only option is "recursive". `c()` is supposed to make a list, right? I split out the `startsWith(names(myTable2), whatToMatch[1])` to test it, and it gave me a logical vector with whether each column name started with "before" in this case. Then, when I put `myTable2` with brackets around it, it just gives me the first 3 rows of data, with all the variables still intact.

Comment: Thanks for the intro to startsWith, though. More intuitive than grep, IMO. Correction to above comment: When I put `myTable2` with brackets around it, it just gives me rows 2:4 of the data, with all the variables still intact. My guess is because it is using the "TRUE" outputs as the indices for subsetting.

Comment: `sep = ` is a named argument to `c` passed as `...` -- e.g. `c(sep = "", a = 2, '1 != 2' = TRUE, fac = factor(1))` returns a named "character" vector with values its `...` arguments and "names" the taggings of `...`. The subsetting you observe, I guess, is because you're subsetting a "data.table" with the "logical" vector and not a "data.frame". Just to get a grasp of what `c(sep = "", a subset of myTable2)` is doing that is passed to `do.call`, try converting your `myTable2` to "data.frame". You could, also, add a "data.table" tag if you need a specific "data.table" approach.

Comment: Thank you, @alexis_laz. Trying it as a data.frame did concatenate the correct group of columns! Now it just looks like I have to assign that column using data.frame methods versus data.table. (I could go either way, I just heard with larger files that fread may be quicker).

Comment: With `myTable2` as a "data.table", `for(i in seq_along(whatToMatch)) set(myTable2, , finalVarNames[i], do.call(paste, c(sep = "", myTable2[, startsWith(names(myTable2), whatToMatch[i]), with = FALSE])))` seems to work fine, I think, and should avoid some probable copies of when assigning to "data.frame" (though here, I guess, apart form the structure of the data, no specific column is copied when assigning a new column). Also, there is, probably, a more idiomatic way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Reduce` function to paste selected columns together via specifying the columns by `grep` in the `.SD` syntax. Here is an example of getting the results using `data.table` package:

```
library(stringi); library(data.table)
myTable2[, paste(stri_trans_totitle(whatToMatch), "final", sep = "_") := 
           lapply(whatToMatch, function(wtm) Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep = ""), 
                                             .SD[, grep(wtm, names(myTable2)), with = F]))]

myTable2
#      herenow before1 before2 before3  after1 after2 after3   Before_final       After_final
# 1: 0.3399679      if     and   where     not   here  blank     ifandwhere      nothereblank
# 2: 0.8181909     for      in      by through  blank  blank        forinby throughblankblank
# 3: 0.2237681     and   where            mine  yours   ours       andwhere     mineyoursours
# 4: 0.6161998     and   where              ha    hey    hon       andwhere          haheyhon
# 5: 0.7606252   fifth  eighth     and   where    not   beet fiftheighthand      wherenotbeet
# 6: 0.5525105     and   where     not    fill           are    andwherenot           filler
```

Some benchmark of `do.call` and `Reduce`:

```
dim(myTable2)
# [1] 1572864       9

reduce <- function() myTable2[, paste(stri_trans_totitle(whatToMatch[1:2]), "final", sep = "_") := lapply(whatToMatch[1:2], function(wtm) Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep = ""), .SD[, grep(wtm, names(myTable2)), with = F]))]    
docall <- function() myTable2[, paste(stri_trans_totitle(whatToMatch[1:2]), "final", sep = "_") := lapply(whatToMatch[1:2], function(wtm) do.call(paste, c(sep = "", .SD[, grep(wtm, names(myTable2)), with = F])))]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(docall(), reduce(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# docall() 707.7818  722.6037  767.8923  737.6272  852.4909  868.8202    10
# reduce() 999.4925 1009.5146 1026.6200 1020.4637 1046.7073 1067.7479    10
```

Comment: I think`Reduce(paste, )` is unnecessarily inefficient compared to, its equivalent, `do.call(paste, )` because with `Reduce` all the intermediate "character" vectors are scanned and copied again and again untill the final "character" is made.

Comment: `Reduce` works like `paste(paste(paste(x, y), z), ...)` while `do.call` makes and evaluates a `paste(x, y, z)` call. The former has to (1) cache, (2) scan, (3) copy all intermediate "character" results, while `do.call` allocates the appropriate buffer once and, then, concatenates all the elements. Taking, also, into account the number of columns mentioned in the Q, the difference is more apparent with a benchmark like `x = rep_len(list(rep_len(letters, 1e5)), 50); identical(Reduce(paste, x), do.call(paste, x)); microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Reduce(paste, x), do.call(paste, x), times = 25)`

Comment: For benchmark input, it's generally best to show the code that made it, not just to display its dimensions.